# getting error on click when using navigateTofileView on Contentversion record

Tags: lightning-web-components, navigationmixin.navigate

I am getting below error when clicking the custom file link. Can anyone help me out what mistake I am making in the code?

[image]

Html:

```
<lightning-layout>
        <template for:each={fileRec} for:item="file">
            <div key={file.Id} class="slds-truncate" title="File Title">
                <a onclick={navigateTofileView} data-id={file.ContentDocumentId}>{file.Title}</a>
            </div>
        </template>
    </lightning-layout>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import fetchRecords from '@salesforce/apex/documentTypeFileUploadCls.fetchRecords';

export default class customFileUpload extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId = '';
    fileRec = [];
    error;
    @wire(fetchRecords, { varRecordId: '$recordId' })
    wiredRecords({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.fileRec = data;
            //this.error = undefined
        }
        else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            //this.fileRec = undefined;
        }
    }
    navigateTofileView(event) {
        console.log("recId ## " + event.currentTarget.dataset.id);
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: "standard__recordPage",
            attributes: {
                pageName: 'filePreview',
                recordId: event.currentTarget.dataset.id
                //objectApiName: 'ContentVersion',
                //actionName: 'view'
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Apex:

```
@AuraEnabled( cacheable=true ) 
    public static List <ContentVersion> fetchRecords( String varRecordId ){
        List<ContentVersion> cdList = new List<ContentVersion>();
        List<ContentDocumentLink> cdlList = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink
                                             WHERE LinkedEntityId = :varRecordId];
        Set<Id> cdIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (ContentDocumentLink cdl : cdlList) {
            cdIds.add(cdl.ContentDocumentId); 
        }        
                  return [SELECT ContentDocumentId,ContentLocation,Lastmodifieddate, 
                       Description,FileType,FirstPublishLocationId,Id,Title,FileExtension
                      FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId IN :cdIds];   
        //return cdList;                  
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Update the JS file with the following code:

```
export default class customFileUpload extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
```

Since you have only imported the NavigationMixin and not extended it the way it should be, you are getting this error.